# Cannot create UWP app on VS 2015

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015

I reinstaled my Visual Studio 2015 3 times and evertime i try to create a project (blank UWP app) using visual C# i have 2 problems (ofc i installed the windows 10 sdk)
1. in the MainPage.xaml.cs the visual studio cannot find default classes attached here (e.g : the type or namespace "System" could not be found, in general everything but using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls is missing)
2.the designer doesn't work, I don't know if it is connected with the first problem

Have you got any idea guys? or maybe some of you had the same?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you try building the solution? The .net libraries are now nuget packages and will be installed on first build.

Comment: i tried, did not work, thanks

Comment: It sounds like nuget package restore isn't working. Do you see anything in the build log related to nuget? Have you updated nuget? Are you on the latest win 10 tools? It's possible there were bugs that have been fixed.

Comment: edit:when it comes to nuget, Ive got many warnings like this :
Warning Assembly strong name "C:\Users\tomek\.nuget\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights\1.0.0\lib\portable-win81+wpa81\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll" is either a path which could not be found or it is a full assembly name which is badly formed. If it is a full assembly name it may contain characters that need to be escaped with backslash(\)... App8. Of course I checked this directory but there is only xml file ( the.dll one is missing)

Comment: I solved this, i've deleted everything in .nuget folder, then I typed this in nuget console : Install-Package NuGet.CommandLine to restore packages. Thank you very much ! :)

Comment: Glad it's resolved. If you ever find clear repro steps please report a bug to us so we can investigate. (Disclosure: I work on visual studio at Microsoft)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In order to solve it, I needed to add a Nuget package
`Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform`